# Slow response onTouchEvent in Android View

Tags: android, performance, view, touch

I created a View that listens for touch events and then draw a circle whenever you touched. Currently, it only tracks vertical position of the touch.

There are the interesting code parts:

onTouchEvent:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int actionType = event.getAction();
    if (actionType == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || actionType == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

        int px = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int py = getMeasuredHeight() / 2;

        touchY = (event.getY() - py);

        if (touchY < 25 && touchY > -25) {
            touchY = 0;
        }
        invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, the onDraw:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int px = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    int py = getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
    int radius = px - innerPadding;

    canvas.drawCircle(px, touchY+py, radius - innerPadding, circlePaint);
    canvas.save();
}
```

It works but I find that the circle following the finger is quite slow considering I have a Galaxy S3. It is smooth but it has a delay.

Any advice of how to implement this better?

Thank you.

Comment: canvas.save() in the end of onDraw(Canvas) is clearly wrong. It ① doesn't have matching restore() and ② is useless in the end of onDraw().

Comment: You might save a little time by only calling those `getMeasuredX()` methods once and storing the value.

Comment: @ToddSjolander Thanks for the recommendations. However, it makes no difference to the final result.

Comment: Hmm...I'd pare it down into something super simple - like replace that circle with a dot - and see if it's still slow, then gradually get back to your original intention and see where the problem first appears.  Also, I wonder if the speed of your touch handler has an effect.  That's worth commenting out to see if that changes it.

Comment: Actually after the update to 4.1.1 for my S3, the same code performs far better. The circle follows my finger quite faster. I guess project butter is doing work.